# nfcpy: Can't escape a while loop constantly listening with nfcpy

Tags: python, nfc, keyboardinterrupt

I currently have a python script where I use nfcpy to listen and process when a tag is passed over an ACR122U reader. The end goal is to listen and type the UID of a tag whenever one is scanned. I've already got that part working.

The problem I'm having is that in order for the program not to end after the first tag is scanned, I've surrounded the following line - which initiates the reader and makes it listen for a tag - surrounded in a `while true` loop:

`with nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb') as clf:
    tag = clf.connect(rdwr=rdwr_options)`

However, hitting  `^C` doesn't make the program exit while it's waiting for a tag. It does work to terminate the program when the above mentioned line is not surrounded in a while loop.

I've tried wrapping it in a `try` block and adding a keyboard interrupt exception, but that doesn't do anything.

Here's my code so far:

```
import nfc
import time
import os

def typestr(text,returnatend):
    totype = text
    if returnatend=="false":
        cmd = """osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'delay 0.1' -e 'keystroke "%s"' -e 'end tell' -e 'delay 2.0'""" % totype
    else:
        cmd = """osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'delay 0.1' -e 'keystroke "%s"' -e 'delay 0.1' -e 'key code 36' -e 'end tell' -e 'delay 2.0'""" % totype

    os.system(cmd)

def notification_osx(text,title,subtitle):
    cmd = """osascript -e 'display notification "%s" with title "%s" subtitle "%s"'""" % (text, title, subtitle)
    os.system(cmd)

def on_startup(targets):
    for target in targets:
        target.sensf_req = bytearray.fromhex("0012FC0000")
    return targets

def on_connect(tag):
    print("printing tag")
    print(tag)
    print("printing uid")
    uid = str(tag.identifier).encode("hex").upper()
    typestr(uid,"false")
    notification_osx(uid,"Scanned Card", "Scanned a card with ID:")


rdwr_options = {
    'on-startup': on_startup,
    'on-connect': on_connect,
    'beep-on-connect': False,
}

while True:
    with nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb') as clf:
        tag = clf.connect(rdwr=rdwr_options)
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: @aryamccarthy added my source, it's pretty minimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `clf.connect` method returns `False` when interrupted with Ctrl-C. Your code should evaluate the return value and break the loop if `tag is False`. This is documented under **Return Value** at the end of [ContactlessFrontend.connect](https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/clf.html#nfc.clf.ContactlessFrontend.connect) description.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for the help. I've implemented your suggestion like this: `while True:
        with nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb') as clf:
            tag = clf.connect(rdwr=rdwr_options)
            if tag == False:
                break` however when I do it takes two `^C` keypresses to exit, but only if a tag has been scanned already. Curious if you might have any ideas?

Comment: Systematically excluding other factors might bring further insights. Try disabling the osascript command invocations to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Note that on_connect should return True if you don't want the same tag recognized over and over while it's close to the reader. See the documentation at http://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/clf.html#nfc.clf.ContactlessFrontend.connect